# Looping - amount of years from months

Tags: c#, loops, int

I have a int months (84 for example) and I need to work out how many years that equals so using 84 = 7 years

I need to loop through the initial number and see how many full years are in there and print the result

example:

```
int count = 84;
for (int i = 12; i <= count; i++)
{
years = i;
}
```

This doesn't work of course, it produces '84 years' where I should produce 7 years. I also need to get the remaining months after the year calculation so if the initial number was 85 for example it would result in 7 years 1 month.

Comment: 84 / 12 = 7? You don't need a loop at all

Comment: Why not just divide? 84/12 = 7.

Comment: Why do you need a loop to do this? Whats wrong with 84/12!?

Comment: This is where that math you said you'd never need in real life will come in handy. ;>

Comment: before giving answers like this and downrating my questions please read the whole thing, the 'years' was only part of my problem i have a amount of months and i needed to convert to years and remaining months - granted im probably doing it wrong but this is the way i chose to do it so comments like this wont help me improve my programming skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone who gave a answer :D much appreciated

i got it working like this in the end

```
 int employmentInMonthsAmount = this.MaxEmploymentHistoryInMonths;

                var intcounter = 0;
                int years = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < employmentInMonthsAmount; i++)
                {
                    if (intcounter >= 12)
                    {
                        years++;
                        intcounter = 0;
                    }
                    intcounter++;
                }
                var monthsleft = intcounter;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use standard mathematical operations instead of a loop:

```
int count = 84;
int years = count / 12;
int months = count % 12;
```

First one is **[division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**, second is **[modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**.

Because both `count` and `12` are integers `count/12` returns an integer as well. So for `85` it will return `7`, not `7.1`.

***Update***

Loop version could look like that:

```
count = 84;
years = 0;
for (int i = 12; i <= count; i += 12)
{
    years++;
}
```

Comment: The `%` operator is the remainder operator, not modulus (despite what MSDN says). Remainder and modulus are different when negative numbers are involved.

Comment: Your loop version gives partial years instead of complete years, e.g. for `count = 73` it gives 7 years. You would start at 12 instead of at 1.

Comment: thank you @MarcinJuraszek, i sorted the problem by creating a loop with two counts  -  

int employmentInMonthsAmount = this.Months;

                    var intcounter = 0;
                    int years = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < employmentInMonthsAmount; i++)
                    {
                        if (intcounter >= 12)
                        {
                            years++;
                            intcounter = 0;
                        }
                        intcounter++;
                    }
                    var monthsleft = intcounter;

Answer (score 5):

Doing that with a loop would look like this:

```
int years = 0;
while (count >= 12) {
  count -= 12;
  years++;
}
```

However, you can do the same without looping:

```
int years = count / 12;
count %= 12;
```

Comment: You could just use a for loop. `int years = 0; for (int totalMonths = 84; totalMonths >= 12; totalMonths -= 12) { years++; }`

Comment: @Romoku: Yes, but for someone who is not very familiar with loops that can be harder to follow. Also, you would need to declare `totalMonths` outside the loop, otherwise you can't get to the remaining months.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime();
t = t.AddMonths(84);

int year = t.Year;    // year = 8
int month = t.Month;  // month = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you just need basic math operations:

```
int count = 84;
int years = (int)(count / 12);
int months = count % 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int years = count / 12;
int remainingMonths = count % 12;
```